# Initializing data members in class definition

Tags: c++

I thought this was now valid in c++11?
Have I done something wrong, or is this simply not yet implemented in visual studio 2013 at this time? I can't find anything that says it's not but I can't find anything that says it is either...

```
class Test
{
private:
    int* data_ = nullptr;
};
```

Gives me :-
Error 1 error C2864: 'Test::data_' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class

Comment: This feature isn't currently supported in MSVC12. Here's what you're looking for: http://www.infoq.com/resource/news/2013/07/vs2013_CPP_compliance/en/resources/VC_Roadmap.png

Comment: Please make this an answer so I can accept it. It exactly answers the question wit a reference link too so.

Comment: Eh, I thought there was a dupe of this, but I can't find it. Either way, the picture is a nice touch.

Comment: By the way, this is even easier with the existing C++11 support: `int* data{};`

Comment: I'm actually going to use unique_ptr so the whole issue goes away but it was good to learn :)

Comment: I like that solution much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct. MSVC12, as of the preview, does not support this feature. However, as you can see in the following image, it will when the real release comes later this year:

[image: MSVC12 C++11 and C++14 support]

Until then, you'll have to stick with a constructor initializer list.